# Reference for the integral form of the metric in linearised gravity

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, metric-tensor, linearized-theory

Reference wanted: I was looking for a source for the integral form for the weak field metric in terms of the stress-energy tensor, as given in the wikipedia article on Linearised Gravity. The problem is that this article does not seem to have a reference for that formula, the references I have found on linearised gravity don't have it either. However, it is a very useful formula for someone who does not want to go through all the potential theory required to product it, with the associated risk of losing factors. Basically, I have a small stress-energy tensor with compact support in space, and I want to find the corresponding weak field $g_{ij}$ in a form where I can check all the conventions and reference the result. I would be very grateful for advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Maggiore's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198570740) contains a pedagogical introduction to the theory of gravitational waves; I used it in undergrad with only some basic knowledge of general relativity and I found it quite comprehensible.  The integral formula for the weak field metric in terms of the stress tensor is presented in chapter 3, where assorted approximations (weak field, low velocity) are taken.

(If you can't find a physical copy, I think the free preview on Amazon displays enough material for you to be able to get to the expression you want.)